# Two images in the same if

Tags: php

I'm using jQueryZoom that need two images to be displayed like this (one image for the 'a' tag and another for the 'img'):

```
<a href="images/BIGIMAGE.JPG">  
    <img src="images/SMALLIMAGE.JPG">  
</a>
```

But I need bring those images from two diferents directories from MySQL (the default directory: 'zoom' and the directory: 'normal'. So I'm trying this on my HTML body:

```
<?php if ( $imagePath = $results02['adaptador']->getImagePathFrontend() && $imagePathNormal = $results02['adaptador']->getImagePathFrontend( IMG_TYPE_NORMAL ) ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $imagePath ?>"  rel='gal1' id="demo1" >
        <img src="<?php echo $imagePathNormal ?>" />
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

It's bringing me just the second one. In the first one it's returns a true value (1). This is the code after load the page on the browser:

```
<a href="1"  rel='gal1' id="demo1" >
   <img src="../../images/produtos/adaptadores/normal/Adaptador 2P.png" />
</a>
```

Why the 'if' is returning true on the first option instead of the image path like in the second one?

Comment: This does not seem related in any way to jQuery so I removed the tag.

Comment: Sorry Jeroen... but its jQueryZoom (based on jQuery)... I think they are related... the issue is about 'PHP IF' but the subjects are related.

Comment: Not really, you are writing html source code using php. How you use it afterwards in the browser is not important here; it's the html that did not get written correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set image path outside or put parenthesis around it. your order of operations is probably confusing you

```
<?php 
$imagePath = $results02['adaptador']->getImagePathFrontend();
if ( $imagePath && $imagePathNormal = $results02['adaptador']->getImagePathFrontend( IMG_TYPE_NORMAL ) ) { ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $imagePath ?>"  rel='gal1' id="demo1" ><img src="<?php echo $imagePathNormal ?>" /></a>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It work's Seth... I didnt understand this change of order but I will try to figure it out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You have to group the assignments separately. Right now you're assigning to `$imagePath` the result of a boolean operation.

```
if ( ($imagePath = $results02['adaptador']->getImagePathFrontend()) &&
     ($imagePathNormal = $results02['adaptador']->getImagePathFrontend( IMG_TYPE_NORMAL )) )
{
    // ...
}
```